# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/updated-march-14-design-for-graphicdesign-se).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://cdn.sstatic.net/graphicdesign/img/favicon.ico

http://cdn.sstatic.net/graphicdesignmeta/img/favicon.ico

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Yaaaaaaay! Thanks so much! We're official! :D

Comment: We are _real_ now :D

Comment: Fantastic. This looks great, Stéphane!

Comment: I love the text selection colours matching the block colour - nice subtle detail that really adds something. [`::selection { background: #XXXXXX; }`](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/) eh, I'll need to remember that one...

Comment: Favicon looks like [Borderlands vault sign](https://www.google.com/search?q=borderlands+vault+icon&tbm=isch). You guys might wanna fix it a bit, being graphic design site and all

Comment: Also you can't tell url'd text in comments without hovering cursor above it. What gives?

Comment: So I've been MIA for a few weeks, just came back to this and needless to say I am more than pleasantly surprised. To the designer Stéphane, the site looks fantastic, thank you for this beautiful design!!

Comment: @user1306322  No highlight for hyperlinks is definitely a problem, but at least the issue seems to be restricted to comments on meta; on regular Q&A pages links show up in the light blue.  So hopefully a quick fix?

Answer (score 6):

Fantastic. It'll take some getting used to but overall I like it.. and I like the meta rework as well.

Answer (score 5):

My instant reaction: ooh nice! fresh! finally!

Also, it came sooner than expected.

First bug (sorry to be a moaner): it's hard to tell where each answer begins and ends without a line between them.

Comment: Each **answer** now has a line between them, but there also needs to be one below the question and above the ["N answers/active/oldest/votes] answer header.

Answer (score 1):

Bug. For some reason embedding images stopped working the modal is under the gray area.

For me this launched mid edit :)

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Comment: this has been fixed on live right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stephane it looks terrific!

The more I use it for actual answering, the more I like it. All minor things I dislike aside, the letter-spacing and font choice is superb in the answer/comment fields! Makes typing a pleasure.