# GRAPHIC DESIGN site logo : Who made this ? And why it is like this?

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation, site-redesign

I was wondering, why our beloved site [**GRAPHIC** DESIGN](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) is having a logo like this. I am not saying it is bad or good. Just curious that who made it, and what was the thought process of making a logo like this.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In [this announcement of the design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/updated-march-14-design-for-graphicdesign-se), Stéphane Martin, the creator, motivates some of his choices. The answers to the 'question' represent the critique we, as a community, had on the design, and you can see the changes Stéphane made in reaction to that. The shape and typography of the logo was a large part of this critique and underwent quite the development.

Comment: My two pennies: I love our logo and site more and more. Popping into other SE-sites is now painful to the eye. MUCH kudos to Stéphane.